# URL mod rewrite help

Tags: mod-rewrite

I cant get mod rewrite to work with the url in example 1 but example 2 works fine I think it has something to do with the url encoding how can I get example 1 to work? All the original URLS work fine/

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/tag/%26amp%3B
```

Original URL

```
http://www.example.com/tag/index.php?tag=%26amp%3B
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/tag/some-tag
```

Original URL

```
http://www.example.com/tag/index.php?tag=some-tag
```

mod rewrite code

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/?)$ /tag/index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `%` for the percent-encoded words:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-%]+)/?$ /tag/index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` only allows alphanumeric content, and there are `%` signs in *Example 1*. If the `tag` part is always going to be present, then you probably want something like `^tag/(.*)$`